# using if else with LINQ Where

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to generate dynamic query to check manage the where clause with number of parameters available...if some parameter is null i don't want to include it in the where clause

```
var test = from p in _db.test
           where if(str1 != null){p.test == str} else i dnt wanna check p.test
```

I have around 14 parameters for the where clause

need help,
thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in steps:

```
// set up the "main query"
var test = from p in _db.test select _db.test;
// if str1 is not null, add a where-condition
if(str1 != null)
{
    test = test.Where(p => p.test == str);
}
```

Comment: Note that sometimes you won't be able to use `var` here because the compile-time type of `_db.test` may be more specific than the `IEnumerable<T>` returned by `Where`. Also note that you can't use just "from p in _db.test" on its own ;)

Comment: i have around 14 parameter for the where clause..does it it mean i have to check for every parameter...is there any way to make this query dynamic, what if more than one parameter is null :)

Comment: @Jon: ha, I was a bit distracted when writing so I forgot the select. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Hasan: there is no magic bullet. If you want to include certain parameters in the query based on certain conditions, you will need to check those conditions in some way.

Comment: @Jon that means I have to make combination of 14 pairs...thats huge

Comment: @Hasan, no you just have 14 if statements. I do this all the time for optional filter parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Fredrik's answer, you can also use the short-circuit rules when evaluating boolean expressions like so:

```
var test = from p in _db.test
           where str1 == null || p.test == str1;
```

**Edit** If you have lots of strings to test, (`str1`, `str2`, etc...) then you can use the following, which will be translated to an SQL `IN` clause:

```
var strings = new List<string>();
if (str1 != null) strings.Add(str1);
if (str2 != null) strings.Add(str2);
if (str3 != null) strings.Add(str3);
...

var test = from p in _db.test
           where strings.Contains(p.test);
```

It's even easier if your strings are already in a collection (which, if you've got 14 of them, I assume they would be...)

Comment: If str1 == null I dont wanna check p.test...and i have 14 strings

Comment: @Hasan: that is exactly what @Dean is writing: if `str == null`, `p.test == str1` will not be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Consider param1 and param2 are the parameters. Your query should be as under:

```
string param1 = "Value1";
string param2 = "Value2";

var q = from bal in context.FxBalanceDetails
        where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1) || bal.Column1 == param1)
               && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2) || bal.Column2 == param2)
        select bal;
```

This will ensure that the where clause gets applied for the particular parameter only when it is not null.

Comment: I'd be careful doing everything in one where clause. I think if your linq provider (EF, L2S, NH, etc) can't convert something inside the where clause to SQL you'll probably end up pulling the entire table into memory.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. LINQ can generate pretty nasty SQL sometimes. I've used this method in SPs very successfully though.

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = 
from p in _db.test
where p.str1 != null ? p.str1 : ""
select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you check the strings against the same Field of the entity?
If so you can write something like:

```
var strings = new[] { "foo", "bar", "ok", "", null };
var query = dataContext.YourTable.AsQueryable();
query = strings.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
       .ToList()
       .Aggregate(query, (q, s) => q.Where(e => e.YourField == s));
```

EDIT:
The previous solution is overcomplicated:

```
var strings = new[] { "foo", "bar", "ok", "", null }.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
       .ToList();
var query = dataContext.YourTable.Where(e => strings.Contains(e.YourField));
```